# Algorithm for laying out images of different sizes in a grid-like way

Tags: iphone, objective-c, algorithm, layout

I'm trying to lay out images in a grid, with a few featured ones being 4x as big.
I'm sure it's a well known layout algorithm, but i don't know what it is called.

The effect I'm looking for is similar to the screenshot shown below. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**UPDATED**
To be more specific, lets limit it to the case of there being only the two sizes shown in the example. There can be an infinite number of items, with a set margin between them. Hope that clarifies things.

[image]

Comment: Are they all multiples of the same base size like in that picture, or can the image-size be arbitrary?

Comment: If the sizes are arbitrary, this sounds similar to the 2D bin packing problem which is NP-hard. Google for some approximation algorithms though.

[link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem)

Comment: If you have an arbitrary number of images, and they are all multiples of the same size, then a trivial greedy algorithm works.  Just place each image in the next available slot and you will get a layout with no asymptotically wasted space.  Of course this problem as it is written is probably too vague to answer definitively.  You need to put some specifications on the size of each image, the number of images, desired spacing and the size of the display window.  After adding in that information, then you need to say what you want to optimize.  Without knowing what you want, this is ill posed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solved with a heatmap or a treemap. Heatmaps often use space-filling-curves. A heatmap reduces the 2d complexity to a 1d complexity. A heatmap looks like a quadtree. You want to look for Nick's hilbert curve quadtree spatial index blog.

Answer (score 4):

There is a well-known layout algorithm called [treemapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping), which is perhaps a bit too generic for your specific problem with some images being 4x as big, but could still be applicable particularly if you decide you want to have arbitrary sizes.

There are several different rectangular treemap algorithms, any of which could be used to visualise photos.  [Here is a nice example](http://tashian.com/carl/archives/2004/06/data_visualizat.php), which uses the strip algorithm to lay out photos with each size proportional to the rating of the photo.